# Extend Metric Space Challenge

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, contest-math, normed-spaces

Let $(E, D)$ be a metric space.

Consider $D_1: E\times E \to \mathbb{R}$ where
$$
D_1(x,y)=\frac{D(x,y)}{1+ D(x,y)}.
$$

I read some note about it but I want to find why $D_1$ is also a metric and 
$$
D_1(x,y) \le \min \{ 1, D(x, y)\}.
$$

Could anyone help me?

Comment: I fixed $<$ into $\le$ in the inequality (with $<$ it's clearly false). Do you have problems in showing that $D_1(x,y)\le 1$ and $D_1(x,y)\le D(x,y)$? I don't think so, so just the triangle inequality for $D_1$ is the problem.

Comment: Dear @egreg, thanks so much.

Comment: Dear @egreg, would u please explain more detail ?

Comment: What, specifically? $D_1(x,y)\le 1$, because $D(x,y)\le 1+D(x,y)$; moreover $D_1(x,y)\le D(x,y)$ because $1\le 1+D(x,y)$. In other words we are using that $a/(1+a)\le 1$ and $a/(1+a)\le a$ for $a\ge0$; then $a/(1+a)\le\min\{1,a\}$; use $a=D(x,y)$.

Comment: i know it, but as a formal proof, would you please submit as an answer ? thanks  so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two of the three properties of a metric are obviously satisfied by $D_1$, namely that

1. $D_1(x,y)\ge0$ and $D_1(x,y)=0$ if and only if $x=y$
2. $D_1(x,y)=D_1(y,x)$

because they hold for $D$. Also, from
$$
\frac{a}{1+a}\le 1,\qquad \frac{a}{1+a}\le a
$$
which are easily verified for $a\ge0$, you can derive
$$
\frac{a}{1+a}\le \min\{1,a\}
$$
Now set $a=D(x,y)$ and you have the last inequality.

The most difficult property is the triangle inequality, that is
$$
D_1(x,z)\le D_1(x,y)+D_1(y,z)
$$
or
$$
\frac{c}{1+c}\le\frac{a}{1+a}+\frac{b}{1+b}
$$
where $c=D(x,z)$, $a=D(x,y)$ and $b=D(y,z)$, where we know that $c\le a+b$ by the triangle inequality satisfied by $D$.

We can clear denominators, because we know that $a\ge0$, $b\ge0$ and $c\ge0$, so we have to prove that
$$
c(1+a)(1+b)\le a(1+b)(1+c)+b(1+a)(1+c)
$$
or
$$
c+ac+bc+abc\le a+ab+ac+abc+b+ab+bc+abc
$$
that becomes
$$
c\le a+2ab+b+abc
$$
that will be verified as soon as we prove the stronger inequality
$$
a+b\le a+2ab+b+abc
$$
that's of course true.